# outline on only 3 borders with box shadow not taking care of border radius

Tags: html, css, border, outline

I have following structure

```
<div class="input-container" data-language="fr-CA">
     <input class="input-arrows" data-min="0" data-max="100">
     <span class="input-symbol">%</span>
     <div>
        <button data-add="10">+</button>
        <button data-add="-10">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to apply an outline around the input and the buttons on focus.
For this I use following CSS (CSS is applied on the input and the parent div of the buttons)

```
.with_arrows.input-focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7), -3px 0 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7), 0 -3px 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7);
    border-right: none;
}
.buttons-focus {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7), 3px 0 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7), 0 -3px 0 rgba(133, 209, 220, 0.7);
    border: 1px solid $primary-700 !important;
}
```

This is the result
[image: Input with box shadow and issue on border radius]

How can I fix this to work like an outline effect ?

(for reference, this is the result of an outline around an input)
[image: input with outline]

**EDIT:**

Adding 4px for the blur radius gives this result. Which is not the wanted result
[image]

Comment: `box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px color`

Comment: This will put the box-shadow around all sides right ? I only need the left, top, bottom on the input for example

Comment: Can you show a mock image of how exactly it is _supposed_ to look?